# Data type for numbers with maximum length in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to store number that can be of length more than 20 digit but not has maximum length defined.

I search for the datatype that hold maximum value entered and found `varchar(max)`, I want to have something like `numeric(max)` but that is not there.

What should I use, is it fine to use `varchar(max)` but then how can I validate for number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it fine to use `varchar(max)` but then how can I validate for number?

You can use a check constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE Numbers (
     n varchar(max) not null,
     constraint CK_Numeric CHECK (n not like '%[^0-9]%')
)
```

The check constraint is ensuring that no character within the `n` column is from outside of the range 0-9. It's a double negative, but it's the easiest way to express the condition. If the values can include decimals, you might want a more complex check:

```
CREATE TABLE Decimals (
     d varchar(max) not null,
     constraint CK_Numeric CHECK (
        d not like '%[^0-9.]%' AND
        LEN(d) - LEN(REPLACE(d,'.','')) in (0,1))
)
```

Which is saying that `.` is now allowed, and the `LEN` check is ensuring it only appears 0 or 1 times in the string.

Answer (score 1):

[`bigint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) has the range of -2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807), so may suit your needs.

There are no larger integer types in SQL Server, so you may have to settle for a character based field (with all the conversions and sorting issues associated with storing numeric data in a text field).

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/719587-long-numbers-sql-server.html),

> the datatype "float" definetly has the largest number support and supports numbers with 309 (!!!) digits.

It depends if your number is integer, real, negative possible ..

Think really deeply if you are planning to use a `varchar(max)` to store numbers. The type of the columns in the database is (for me) the most important point to ensure the data consistency. So it is possible but is it really necessary?

Comment: It doesn't really allow you to store 309 digits. It allows you to store a number that, if written out, would require 309 digits to write it, but a lot of those will be `0`s. The maximum *precision* is [only 15 digits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx).